# Expanded and flexible not filling entire row

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

Hello I have the below code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:
       Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
             // FlexibleWidget(),
              ExpandedWidget(),
              FlexibleWidget(),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ExpandedWidget(),
              ExpandedWidget(),
            ],
          ),
          Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              FlexibleWidget(),
              FlexibleWidget(),
            ],
          ),
          Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              FlexibleWidget(),
              ExpandedWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
     ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text(
            'Expanded',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlexibleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text(
            'Flexible',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the result is this:

[image: Expanded Flexible]

Shoudln't the first container fill the space left after the flexible widget is set? Since it also belongs to a column with a child of 2 expanded widgets, the column width size should be the entire screen. That means the row should be the entire screen too. I would have expected the expanded green widget in the first row to fill the row until there is no white left like the image below:

[image: expanded]

Instead it only fills half the page. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

Comment: This throws an error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me start with FlexFit before coming to the point. `FlexFit.tight` allows the children to fill rest of the space but `FlexFit.loose` allows children to size themselves as they want.

Now, as you might know `Expanded` is nothing but Flexible with tight-fitting i.e. `fit: FlexFit.tight`.

```
Expanded(
  child: child,
)

is equivalent to

Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: child,
)
```

Now, Let's take your example.

For the first block, there are two widgets with Flex 1 (by default), which will divide the screen to two half; each will be given 50%. This does not mean that they have to take 50% of the screen. It means that they can expand to 50% of the screen. So, the `Expanded` widget does that. It takes 50% of the screen as it has tight-fitting.

Coming to the `Flexible` widget, by default, it follows loose-fitting. So it says to its children that they can expand till 50% but there is no boundation that they have to take all space. They can take whatever space they want but the upper bound is set to 50%. In your case, it only needs the space to fit "Flexible" text with some padding. So it takes that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What I don't quite understand is why do the widgets, each take 50% of available space, the image below is from the flutter widget of the week video and in that case every widget should be 1/3 of the available space but the flexible one cleary extends its own 1/3. In any case how can I fill the entire row?

Comment: It is because of Flex property. If there are two widgets in a row, each with flex : 1, it means that divide the available space between two widgets. Here, the available space is 100% which is screen-size. So these widget gets half of the screen size for each.

You might need to understand basic layout functionality.. Check out this really great article. Hope it will solve your concepts.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2

Comment: Thanks, I now understand that it is because TWO of these widgets have a flex factor.

Comment: It is a good explanation why it behaves like this. But how can we achieve that the `Expanded` boxes take the rest in case the `Flexible` does not take half the screen?

Comment: I posted an answer how to achieve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/74310309/386201

Comment: but how to have expanded take all the space while the other take only what they require. I want flexible and expandable widgets' functionality. E.g.: dynamic text taking space it requires inside row with other flexible and expanded dynamic text/widgets.

Answer (score 3):

Pushpendra explained how flex works and why they take at most half the screen when using two flex items. However, there is no answer showing how to make **one item fill the rest of the space including space that is not taken by the other item**.

**The trick** is to only use a single flex item that takes all space (`Expanded`) and constraining the other item to `maxWidth = half of the available width`. This can be achived using `LayoutBuilder` to get the available width and `ConstraintedBox` to constrain one widget without using flex - which allows the `Expanded` to take more than half of the space (all that is not taken by the `ConstrainedBox`):

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.5),
        child: Text(
          text1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          softWrap: false,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          text2,
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          softWrap: false,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
});
```